# How to extract a float from a string after a keyword in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string from which I need to extract the value 14.123456 which is directly after the keyword airline_freq: (which is a unique keyword in my string)

Please help find the correct regex (indexing m.group() doesn't work beyond 0)

```
import re
s =  "DATA:init:     221.000OTHER:airline_freq:  14.123456FEATURE:airline_amp:   0.333887 more text"
m = re.search(r'[airline_freq:\s]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', s)
m.group()

$ result 221.000
```

Comment: Try `r'airline_freq:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'` oh and `print(m.group(1))`

Comment: and what if the float values were sometimes positive and sometimes negative?( using a - to indicate neg)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use this:

```
(?<=airline_freq:)\s*(?:-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))
```

This uses a lookbehind to enforce that the number is preceded by `airline_freq:` but it does not make it part of the match.

The number-matching part of the regex can match numbers with or without `.` and, if there is `.`, it can also be just leading or trailing (in this case clearly not before the `-` sign). You can also allow an optional `+` instead of the `-`, by using `[+-]` instead of `-`.

Unfortunately it seems Python does not allow variable length lookbehind, so I cannot put the `\s*` in it; the consequence is that the spaces between the `:` and the number are part of the match. This in general could be no problem, as leading spaces when giving a number to a program are generally skipped automatically.

However, you can still remove the first `?:` in the regex above to make the number-matching group capturing, so that the number is available as `\1`.

The example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/Nvu0Pi/1).

Comment: and what if the float values were sometimes positive and sometimes negative?( using a - to indicate neg)

Comment: @Thediz, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

This will match only the float as a single group.

```
r'airline_freq:\s+([-0-9.]+)'

"DATA:init:     221.000OTHER:airline_freq:  14.123456FEATURE:airline_amp:   0.333887 more text"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

`(?<=airline_freq\:\s\s)(\d+\.\d+)`

```
In [2]: import re
   ...: s =  "DATA:init:     221.000OTHER:airline_freq:  14.123456FEATURE:airline_amp:   0.333887 more text"
   ...: m = re.search(r'(?<=airline_freq\:\s\s)(\d+\.\d+)', s)
   ...: m.group()
Out[2]: '14.123456'
```

Test: https://regexr.com/51q41

If you're not sure about the number of spaces between airline_freq: and the desired float number, you can use:

`(?<=airline_freq\:)\s*(\d+\.\d+)`

and `m.group().lstrip()` to get rid of the left spaces.

Comment: This makes the assumption that there are exactly two spaces between the colon and the number.